# jQuery UI Dropdown value doesnt change

Tags: jquery-ui, drop-down-menu

I have a dropdown menu which contains 3 options. This menu is shown inside a modal `jQuery UI` dialog.

I can open open the dialog and choose one of the three options. The chosen option is stored in a variable. This works fine. But if I open the dialog again and choose another option, the variable does not change - it contains the value of first selection.

```
$("#button").click(function() 
{   
    var diag = "<select id='diagDropdown'>"
            +"<option>Option 1</option>"
            +"<option>Option 2</option>"
            +"<option>Option 3</option>"
               +"</select>";

    $(diag).dialog(
        {title: "Choose Option"},
        {autoOpen: "false"},
        {modal: "true"},
        {draggable: "false"},
        { buttons: {OK: dialogOK} });       

    function dialogOK() 
    {
        var chosenOption=$("#diagDropdown option:selected").val().toLowerCase();

        //working with chosen option
        $(this).dialog("close");                                                                
    });
```

Hope you can help me. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that each time you click on your element with id "**button**", you are creating a new dropdown with id "**diagDropdown**" in a new dialog.

Then your code :

```
var chosenOption=$("#diagDropdown option:selected").val().toLowerCase();
```

is always selecting the first dropdown with id "**diagDropdown**" in the DOM.

Try this :

```
<input type="button" value="click me" id="button"/>

<script type="text/javascript">
    // On DOM ready
    $(function() {

        var dropdown = 
            $('<select id="diagDropdown"> ' +
                '<option>Option 1</option>' +
                '<option>Option 2</option>' +
                 '<option>Option 3</option>' +
             '</select>');

        // Create the dialog (only once)
        dropdown.dialog({
            title: "Choose Option",
            autoOpen: false,
            modal: true,
            draggable: false,
            buttons: {
                "OK": function() {
                    var chosenOption=$('#diagDropdown option:selected').val().toLowerCase();
                    //working with chosen option
                    $(this).dialog('close');
                }
            }
        });

        // Bind click event : on click just open the existing dialog 
            $('#button').click(function() {
                $('#diagDropdown').dialog('open');
            });
    });
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks for your response. I already thought that it'll work this way. But isn't there a way to do it without creating more html-elements? javascript-only?

Comment: This code is appending less html elements in the dom than the one you wrote but if you mean that you want the <select> element to be created using javascript you can, i edited my answer to reflect that.